# How to add quotes to gval expression

Tags: go, expression

I read JSON file to get expression to evaluate by gval library. I want it to compile JSON string having values in a string slice.

```
func main() {
    jsonConfig := `{"exp": "\"{\" + \"\\u0022\" + fields[0] + \"\\u0022\" + \": \" + \"\\u0022\" + fields[1] + \"\\u0022\" + \"}\""}`

    m := map[string]string{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonConfig), &m)

    values := []string{"fieldA", "valA"}
    res, err := gval.Evaluate(m["exp"], map[string]interface{}{"fields": values})

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed to evaluate: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("success: (%T) %v\n", res, res)
}
```

The result is

```
success: (string) {"fieldA": "valA"}
```

The problem is to add quotes to expression. I used `\u0022` but it seems to me awkward. Is there any other way?

Comment: What would be the expected output ?

Comment: `{"fieldA": "valA"}` is a proper output. But expression is very poorly readable

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the unmarshal you are doing is necessary, you should be able to just modify the config and pass it directly into `gval.Evaluate` - see below:

```
    main() {
        config := `"{\"" + fields[0] + "\":\" " + fields[1] + "\"}"`
        values := []string{"fieldA", "valA"}
        res, err := gval.Evaluate(config, map[string]interface{}{"fields": values})
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("failed to evaluate: %v\n", err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("success: (%T) %v\n", res, res)
    }
```

The result will be:

```
    success: (string) {"fieldA":" valA"}
```